# Ionic 3 - How to retrieve firebase data after facebook login

Tags: angular, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I need to get firebase data (uid,name,email) after facebook login.

My Code:

```
this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
  .then((retorno: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
    const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(retorno.authResponse.accessToken);

    this.resultado_facebook = firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(facebookCredential);
    console.log(this.resultado_facebook);
})
```

Result:
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9wP2.png)

But I can't get data from the result.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)` returns `firebase.Promise` containing non-null `firebase.auth.UserCredential`

The `UserCredential` has the `user` property with desired fields like `uid, email, displayName`

Here is the updated code:

```
this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
  .then((retorno: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
    const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(retorno.authResponse.accessToken);

    firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(facebookCredential)
                        .then(credential => {
                           this.resultado_facebook = credential.user;
                           console.log(this.resultado_facebook);
                           console.log('UID = ', this.resultado_facebook.uid);
                         })
   })
```

Comment: Hey, dude, thank you. So simple and I did not think of it. Saved my day.